# trying to understand a code fragment of an article on socket.io and redis

Tags: redis, socket.io

I'm trying to understand an article [here](http://www.codedevlog.com/blog/2014/10/23/socket-dot-io-user-sessions-with-redis-and-json-web-tokens/), and now everything is clear but one code fragment, mentioned on pre-last code block, with a total of 1 to 17 lines, and this fragment is from line 1 to 9:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
   redis.get(req.user.email, function(err, id) {
     if (err) next(err);
      req.emitToUser = function() {
        var soc = id && io.to(id);
        soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);
     }
  });
});
```

and I think its some shortcomings in my javascript knowledge are the root cause. 
My knowledge over this code fragment:

- The 'apply' method will execute the 'emit' with 'soc' as 'this' value
  and feeds the 'emit' method with 'arguments' (am I right here
  please?)
- socket.id is related to the email of socket owner, because id.to(id) is based on the fact that the socket.id is the room where every socket is joined with itself. Redis provides the key-value data structure that holds user email as key, and the value is the socket.id.

problems:

- where 'arguments' is coming from?
- what's the purpose of this code fragment?

Please make me clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with this code, but the general idea is to define a method on the `req` object `req.emitToUser()` for every incoming request that will allow some other route handler later in the chain to use that method to emit to the user who make the request.  This is a common desire to want to connect a currently connected socket.io connection to the user making the http request.

Let's look at each line here:

```
redis.get(req.user.email, function(err, id) {
```

Look up the req.user.email in the redis database to get a socket.io id associated with that email that has previously been saved in that redis database.

```
if (err) next(err);
```

If it wasn't found in redis, make this request fail with an error.

```
req.emitToUser = function() {
```

Assign a new method to the current `req` object so that other route handlers later in the chain can use that method.

```
 var soc = id && io.to(id);
```

Look up the id value in socket.io to get the socket for that id.  Technically `io.to()` doesn't return the socket, but it returns an object that you can call `emit()` on that will send to that socket.

```
soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);
```

The role of `soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);` is this:

1. Execute the `soc.emit()` method
2. Set the `this` value when executing that method to the `soc` object.
3. Set the arguments when executing that method to whatever the arguments were that were passed to `req.emitToUser(x, y, z)` when it was called.

Here's a more concrete example:

```
function fn(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

fn.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Using `fn.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);` will be the same as:

```
fn(1, 2, 3);
```

Now, you'd likely never use `.apply()` in this exact way when the arguments are already known.  The case for using it is when you have some arbitrary array that is passed to you (you don't know what's in it) and you want to pass those arguments along to some other function in the exact same order as they were given to you.  That's what `soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);` is doing.  It's taking the `arguments` object (which is an array-like structure that represents the arguments that were passed to the parent function `req.emitToUser()` and passing those exact arguments on it `sock.emit()`.  If you knew exactly how many arguments there would be, then you could hard-code that same code as this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
   redis.get(req.user.email, function(err, id) {
     if (err) next(err);
      req.emitToUser = function(msg, data) {
        var soc = id && io.to(id);
        soc.emit(msg, data);
     }
  });
});
```

But, `.apply()` creates a more generic solution that will work regardless of how many arguments were passed to `req.emitToUser()` as it will just pass all the arguments on to `soc.emit()`.

---

This line of code is a bit suspect:

```
var soc = id && io.to(id);
```

It appears to be trying to protect against there not being a proper id returned from redis earlier.  But, if there's no id, then `soc` will not be a valid object and the following like of code:

```
soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);
```

will throw.  So, the `id && io.to(id)` isn't really providing the proper protection.  It appears this should more likely be:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
   redis.get(req.user.email, function(err, id) {
     if (err) next(err);
      req.emitToUser = function() {
        if (id) {
            var soc = io.to(id);
            soc.emit.apply(soc, arguments);
        } else {
            // not sure what you want here, perhaps return an error
            // or throw a more meaningful exception
        }
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: @AdrianDain - Did this answer your question?

Comment: @AdrianDain - Why are you posting new questions without even providing any response here yet?  As it stands now, it feels like there's little reason to help you because you disappear for two weeks and then, even when you come back, don't offer any feedback on the answers.  It's like trying to help a brick wall - that's the level of engagement I'm feeling from you right now.  This place is two-way street.  The more you engage, the more people will help you.  It's not a drive-by question place.  Drop a question, come back two weeks later.

Comment: @AdrianDain - The point is that you should be responsive here (in hours, not weeks) and provide some indication whether this answered your question or not.  If not, then please explain what is not answered yet so we can finish off this question.  If your question is now answered, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to "accept" it as the best answer and finish this question.

Comment: @AdrianDain - I added a bunch more explanation for `.apply()` in my answer.  In the future if you don't understand something in the answer, then tell us what you don't yet understand.

Comment: I deleted those of my comments not related to the topic of the page for not to bother other readers if any. Thank you so much for a response over 100% clear! In fact I have now no question over why to ever use "apply", and my confusion with soc = id && io.to(id); (my main problem) is gone. Perfect!

Comment: I just could comment this part "This is a common desire to...", that I think you mean that it is a design pattern, and if my guess is correct and you possibly have any link to an example of such a DP with socket.io, I'd grateful to have access to. I didn't know about that and now it is my question too! Thank you again.

Comment: @AdrianDain - There are many different ways to do it.  Here's one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session